# How to set asp:checkboxlist cssclass with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to apply a cssclass to my asp:checkboxlist with jquery. My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CheckBoxList1").attr("CssClass", "CheckBoxSubjects");
    });
```

but when the pageloads the class is not being applied to the checkboxlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** method in jQuery to add a class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#CheckBoxList1").addClass("CheckBoxSubjects");
});
```

***Note :*** To add multiple class separate them by using a space

Comment: Thank you sir. The more I use jQuery, the more I'm liking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CheckBoxList1").addClass("CheckBoxSubjects");
});
```

Comment: why posting duplicate answer ??

Comment: Before updated the first answer, it was looking like `$("#CheckBoxList1").addClass("CssClass");`